# Writing data from HDFS to Kafka

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-kafka

Kafka is commonly used in ingestion pipeline when data is finally written to HDFS. Are there any designs where Kafka is used to transfer data from HDFS to external systems? I understand that Kafka is more suitable as a messaging system, but can we use the publish-subscribe of Kafka for transferring data? In this use case, producers will write data from HDFS (1 row at a time) to the topics and consumers will read asynchronously.

There might be challenges in implementing this like size of data, security, etc.

I am aware of the other ways, such as sqoop, distcp, etc.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://github.com/linkedin/gobblin)

Comment: @AvihooMamka Gobblin is a data ingestion framework. My requirement is extracting data from HDFS to external target.

Comment: And Gobblin provides that... https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GOBBLIN/HDFS+to+Kafka+Ingestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to implement this using Mapreduce or whatever framework you choose. I'd guess that something like [Apache Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/) could do it out of the box but haven't tried that direction.

Comment: Thanks @Lundahl for sharing Apache nifi, I will investigate further.

Comment: @mbgsuirp NiFi should be a great option for what you describe.  Whether you want data into or out of Kafka, HDFS, and various other systems it should work well.  NiFi was designed to provide an array of security options, handle massive objects as well as tiny events, allow for runtime modification of flows, and to track everything it is doing with event level lineage.  Let us know if you need help.

Comment: Agreed, I plan to check HDF when I get back to this in few weeks.